# Is there an app that will scan a document and upload it to Google Docs?

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, data-synchronization, scanning, google-docs

Is there an iPhone app that allows me to take pictures of documents and then upload them to Google Docs?

Comment: Do you want the picture itself to sync, or are you looking for scan/ocr software?

Comment: @Dori, sorry, I don't mean synch, I mean *upload*

Comment: Do you want the picture itself to upload, or are you looking for scan/ocr software?

Comment: @Dori, I'm looking at something like this: http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-19512_7-10456561-233.html

Comment: You should have added that as an answer, as it appears to answer your question. I've done so; if you want to also add it, I'd be happy to delete mine.

Comment: @Dori, the product I mentioned in my link didn't mention any Google Docs integration, so it's not my choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Scanner Pro](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id333710667) <sup><sub>[iTunes link]</sub></sup> from [Readdle](http://readdle.com/). According to [the product's Web page](http://readdle.com/scannerpro), it integrates with Google Docs and

> lets you use Google Docs OCR to convert scans into editable text files on your Google account.

Answer (score 0):

DocScanner and Genius Scan will also provide this capability (along with upload to Evernote, DropBox, etc.).